# How to prevent re-rendering with useSubscription()?

Tags: react-hooks, apollo, react-apollo, graphql-subscriptions

Many of you might have heard of GraphQL. It provides `QUERY` and `MUTATION`. Also it supports `SUBSCRIPTION` as 100% replacement of `web socket`. I'm a big fan of GraphQL and hooks. Today I faced an issue with `useSubscription` which is a hook version of `SUBSCRIPTION`. When this subscription is fired, a React component is re-rendered. I'm not sure why it causes re-rendering.

```js
import React from 'react'
import { useSubscription } from 'react-apollo'

const Dashboard = () => {
  ...
  useSubscription(query, {
    onSubscriptionData: data => {
      ...
    }
  })

  render (
    <>
      Dashboard
    </>
  )
}
```

Actually `useSubscription`'s API doc doesn't say anything about this re-rendering now. It would be really appreciated if you provide me a good solution to preventing the re-rendering.

Thanks!

Comment: When you receive new data from onSubscriptionData, your component will be re-rendered. It's like a parent pass a prop to its child, when you update this prop, the child component will be re-rendered.

Comment: Hi @Michael, could tell me how to prevent the re-rendering?

Comment: why do you want to prevent re-rendering?

Comment: In the subscription, a Global variable is updated. It is used for calculations, but no triggering re-render. Eventually the global variable should be updated without re-rendering via the subscription.

Answer (score 3):

Just put your subscription in separate component as this [guy did](https://medium.com/@seniv/improve-performance-of-your-react-apollo-application-440692e37026), and return null, now your root component won't rerender

```
function Subscription () {
  const onSubscriptionData = React.useCallback(
    handleSubscription,  // your handler function
    [])

  useSubscription(CHAT_MESSAGE_SUBSCRIPTION, {
    shouldResubscribe: true,
    onSubscriptionData
  })

  return null
}

// then use this component
<Subscription />
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, there is no way to prevent re-render when receiving new data in onSubscriptionData. If your global data is used for calculations, you should use useMemo for you global variable. On the other hand, you should consider do you need put your variable in onSubscriptionData? Are there other ways? Did you use useSubscription in right component? If your have to do that, you have to accept extra rendering. 
Hopefully, my answer is helpful for your situation.